# PyInstaller 4. 4 Qt platform error when launching Maya 2020 from subprocess on one machine only

Tags: python, pyqt5, pyinstaller, maya, pyside2

I have a problem where I cannot lauch Maya 2020 using subprocess.Popen from an application frozen in PyInstaller 4.4. When I launch it, I get the following error:

```
This application failed to start because no Qt platform plugin could be initialized. Reinstalling the application may fix this problem.

Available platform plugins are: minimal, offscreen, webgl, windows, direct2d.
```

The code to start Maya is the following

```
process = subprocess.Popen(dccPath, env=self.getPreparedEnviroment(), creationflags=subprocess.CREATE_NEW_CONSOLE)
```

I have already tried the solution presented in this post, but it did not work.

http://discourse.techart.online/t/unable-to-launch-maya-2022-using-popen-from-a-pyinstaller-exe/13747

I am using Python 3.7.9, PyInstaller 4.4 and PySide2 5.15.2.

Weirdly, it only does not run on one machine and runs on all others that I tried in on. Furthermore, it worked with Python 2.7 and PyQt4. Going back is not an option.
It also works when launching maya directly from Windows or within the application run inside a regular Python environment.

Does anyone have any ideas what might be causing this?

Comment: I've had an error *very* similar to that when importing a broken Qt library recently. I accidentally deployed a version of PySide6 that was missing some key component, and it failed in a similar fashion. Could be worth poking around that particular Maya install manually and see if it all checks out?

Answer (score 1):

I know this is an old thread, but I ran into the same problem and, because solutions for this seem scarce on the internet, I'll write my solution here in case others encounter the same problem.

I followed the same thread as you from [your link](http://discourse.techart.online/t/unable-to-launch-maya-2022-using-popen-from-a-pyinstaller-exe/13747) and then stumbled upon an Autodesk solution [here](https://knowledge.autodesk.com/support/autocad/troubleshooting/caas/sfdcarticles/sfdcarticles/This-application-failed-to-start-because-it-could-not-find-or-load-the-Qt-platform-plugin-dialogue-appears-when-running-a-Nastran-analysis.html). Combined, I found that we need to add `QT_PLUGIN_PATH` (not `QT_QPA_PLUGIN_PATH`) to the environment (either via `maya.env` or set it up using batch file then run it with Popen).

In my case, I added the `QT_PLUGIN_PATH="C:\Program Files\Autodesk\Maya2022\plugins\platforms"` into the environment before calling Maya.